# How to decouple a dependency

Tags: c#, interfaces, dependencies

I am trying to decouple a dependency from Book Class to BookStorage, but got confused how to do this right. Can someone tell me how to decouple this correctly? Here is my code:

```
    public interface IBook
    {
        string Execute(Guid bookId);
    }

    public class Book : IBook
    {
        public string Execute(Guid bookId)
        {
            var Id = 2;
            var storage = new BookStorage(Id);// Decouple this dependency? 

            // Get data
            var response = storage.GetBookData("GOF");
            return response;
        }
    }


    public interface IBookStorage
    {
        string GetBookData(string name);
    }


    public class BookStorage : IBookStorage
    {
        public BookStorage(int id)
        {

        }
        public string GetBookData(string bookName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps a book does not store itself. An entity (book) typically does not implement an interface either. Ideally an entity should not have any dependencies, if it must consider using double dispatch (pass in a IBookStorage on your Exceute method). In this case why not turn it around, pass the Book instance to a Bookstorage? Book.Execute is semantically very poor... What does it mean to execute a book? Can one execute a book?

Answer (score 6):

The point of dependency-injection is to not create the dependencies *within* your class, but to delegate that task to the calling code. So instead of creating a new instance of `BookStorage` within your `Execute`-method pass it as parameter, using the `IBookStorage` interface.

```
public string Execute(Guid bookId, IBookStorage bookStorage)
{
    var Id = 2;

    // Get data
    var response = bookStorage.GetBookData("GOF");
    return response;
}
```

This would change the interface also. If you don´t want to do this you can also pass the dependency via constructor-injection:

```
var book = new Book(new BookStorage("GOF"));
```

which will need this constructor

```
class Book
{
    private readonly IBookStorage storage;
    public Book(IBookStorage storage)
    {
        this.storage = storage;
    }
}
```

EDIT: To improve this desing further you could resolve this dependency using a dependency-injection-container like NInject or similar. But this goes to far for a question here on SO.

Comment: This doesn't break the dependency on a concrete instance of BookStorage, it just moves the coupling into another class.  Personally I would abstract BookStorage to an interface and inject an `IBookStorage` interface into `Book` via a container like Unity or Ninject.  I will say your example illustrates DI without all the plumbing involved in setting up a container though.

Comment: @dparsons Sure, this is true. For the sake of simplicity I omitted DI-container. However if `BookStorage` is just a DTO this won´t make so much sence though.

Comment: The usage of an interface is *essential* for breaking the dependency, so I took the freedom and made some minor changes to your answer to correct that. Note this has nothing to do with using a DI container.

Comment: What should I do if my methods are not abstracted properly? (E.g I have tons of classes with no interfaces). Do I implement poor man's DI?